# Class Limiting and Archetypes

Tags: c#

I'm trying to create a function in C# which will allow me to, when called, return a reference to a given class type.  The only types of functions like this that I have seen are in UnrealScript and even then the functionality is hard coded into its compiler.  I'm wondering if I can do this in C#.  Here's what I mean (code snippet from UnrealScript source):

```
native(278) final function actor Spawn
(
    class<actor>      SpawnClass,
    optional actor    SpawnOwner,
    optional name     SpawnTag,
    optional vector   SpawnLocation,
    optional rotator  SpawnRotation
);
```

Now in UScript you would call it like this...

```
local ActorChild myChildRef; //Ref to ActorChild which Extends 'actor'
myChildRef = Spawn(class'ActorChild' ...);  //rest of parameters taken out
myChildRef.ChildMethod();  //method call to method existing inside class 'ActorChild'
```

Which will return a reference to an object of class 'ActorChild' and set it to variable 'myChildRef.'  I need to do something similar within C#.

I've looked into Generics but it seems that to use them, I need create an instace of the class where my function lies and pass the 'generic' parameter to it.  This isn't very desirable however as I won't need to use the 'Spawn' function for certain classes but I would still need to add the generic parameter to the class whenever I use it.

I guess a simplified question would be, how can I return a type that I do not know at compile time and when the different classes could be far too many to trap.

Pseudo-Code (sticking to UScript class names, i.e. Actor):

```
//Function Sig
public class<Actor> Create(class<Actor> CreatedClass)
{
    return new CreatedClass;
}

//Function call
ActorChild myChild = Create(class'ActorChild');
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: I would like to avoid explicit typecasts that would occur from the class calling Created.  If I can typecast to the desired object within the Created method and return the 'unknown type' whatever that may be, I would be extremely happy.

EDIT 2:  Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than use a generic *class*, use a generic *method*:

```
public T Spawn<T>() where T : new()
{
    return new T();
}
```

Having said that, I assume you want to do more than just blindly create an instance, otherwise you could just call `new MyClass()` yourself.

Comment: Thanks - Apparently I didn't read enough.  I thought to have a generic method, you needed a generic class as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the class System.Type to represent classes. To get references to type objects, you either use typeof (in a scope where the class is actually defined)

```
System.Type t = typeof(ActorChild);
```

or the Type.GetType function (if you only know the name of the type)

```
System.Type t = Type.GetType("NamespaceFoo.ActorChild");
```

You can then use the reflection API to create an instance

```
public object Create(System.Type ClassToCreate)
{
    return ClassToCreate.GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes).Invoke(null);
}
```

Comment: doesn't this suffer from the "Type.GetType only looks in mscorlib" problem?

Comment: Does it really? I understand that if you put ,assemblyname after the type name, it will look in other assemblies as well. See the documentation for AssemblyQualifiedName in MSDN.

Comment: This requires having to typecast to 'object' or typecast 'object' to whatever return value is specified in the method signature.  I would like to avoid that.

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to accomplish can be done quite easily with Reflection and something called Dynamic Method Invocation.

Basically, you'll be using the Type object, the Activator.CreateInstance Method and some other nice classes like MethodInfo and ParameterInfo.

Here's an example to get you started:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;

namespace Reflection
{
    class SomeClass
    {
        private string StringPrimer = "The parameter text is: ";
        public SomeClass(string text)
        {
             Console.WriteLine(StringPrimer + text);
        }
        public string getPrimer() //supplies the Primer in upper case, just for kicks
        {
            return StringPrimer.ToUpper();
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SomeClass s = new SomeClass("this is an example of the classes normal hard-coded function.\nNow try feeding in some text");
            string t = Console.ReadLine();

            Console.WriteLine("Now feed in the class name (SomeClass in this case)");
            Type myType = Type.GetType("Reflection."+Console.ReadLine()); //Stores info about the class.
            object myClass = Activator.CreateInstance(myType, new object[] { t }); //This dynamically calls SomeClass and sends in the text you enter as a parameter

            //Now lets get the string primer, using the getPrimer function, dynamically
            string primer = (string)myType.InvokeMember("getPrimer",
                                                        BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Default,
                                                        null,
                                                        myClass,
                                                        null); //This method takes the name of the method, some Binding flags,
                                                              //a binder object that I left null,
                                                              //the object that the method will be called from (would have been null if the method was static)
                                                              //and an object array of parameters, just like in the CreateInstance method.
            Console.WriteLine(primer);
        }
    }
}
```